# Default argument values in subroutines

Tags: perl, function, subroutine

I don't know how to set default arguments for subroutines. Here is what I considered:

```
sub hello {
  print @_ || "Hello world";
}
```

That works fine for if all you needed was one argument. How would you set default values for multiple arguments?

I was going to do this:

```
sub hello {
  my $say = $_[0] || "Hello";
  my $to  = $_[1] || "World!";
  print "$say $to";
}
```

But that's a lot of work... There must be an easier way; possibly a best practice?

Answer (score 15):

I do it with named arguments like so:

```
sub hello {
    my (%arg) = (
        'foo' => 'default_foo',
        'bar' => 'default_bar',
        @_
    );

}
```

I believe [Params::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Params::Validate) supports default values, but that's more trouble than I like to take.

Answer (score 13):

I usually do something like:

```
sub hello {
    my ($say,$to) = @_;
    $say ||= "Hello";
    $to ||= "World!";
    print "$say $to\n";
}
```

Note that starting from perl 5.10, you can use the "`//=`" operator to test if the variable is defined, and not just non-zero.  (Imagine the call `hello("0","friend")`, which using the above would yield `"Hello friend"`, which might not be what you wanted.  Using the `//=` operator it would yield `"0 friend"`).

Comment: @Davidmoreen: testing an array for definedness isn't useful

Comment: @Davidmoreen, the correct way to say that is `print $_[0] // "Hello world";`.  As ysth said, you can't use `defined` on an array (which is what `//` means), because an array in scalar context returns its length, which is always defined.

Answer (score 7):

Also have a look at [`Method::Signatures`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Method-Signatures/).  This uses [`Devel::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Declare/) to provide some extra (needed!) sugar with the keywords `method` and `func`.

Below is your example using the new `func`:

```
use Method::Signatures;

func hello ($say='Hello', $to='World!') {
    say "$say $to";
}

hello( 'Hello', 'you!' );    # => "Hello you!"
hello( 'Yo' );               # => "Yo World!"
hello();                     # => "Hello World!"
```

/I3az/

Answer (score 5):

If you see the documentation of **Perl Best Practices**: **Default argument Values** by **Damian Conway** then you will find some important points like:

- Resolve any **default argument values** as soon as @_ is unpacked.
- It suggest that if you have many default values to set up then the cleanest way would be factoring out the **defaults into tables ie., a hash**  and then preinitializing the argument hash with that table.

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
  use strict;
  use warning;
  my %myhash = (say => "Hello", to => "Stack Overflow");
  sub hello {
   my ($say, $to) = @_;
   $say =  $say ? $say : $myhash{say};
   $to =  $to ? $to : $myhash{to};
   print "$say $to\n";
  }
  hello('Perl');      # output :Perl Stack Overflow
  hello('','SO');     # output :Hello SO
  hello('Perl','SO'); # output :Perl SO
  hello();            # output :Hello Stack Overflow
```

For more detail and complete example refer **[Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735).**

Answer (score 4):

Because Perl's mechanism for passing arguments to subroutines is a single list, arguments are positional. This makes it hard to provide default values. Some built-ins (e.g. `substr`) handle this by ordering arguments according to how likely they are to be used -- less frequently used arguments appear at the end and have useful defaults.

A cleaner way to do this is by using named arguments. Perl doesn't support named arguments *per se*, but you can emulate them with hashes:

```
use 5.010;  # for //

sub hello {
    my %arg = @_;
    my $say = delete $arg{say} // 'Hello';
    my $to  = delete $arg{to}  // 'World!';
    print "$say $to\n";
}

hello(say => 'Hi', to => 'everyone');  # Hi everyone
hello(say => 'Hi');                    # Hi world!
hello(to  => 'neighbor Bob');          # Hello neighbor Bob
hello();                               # Hello world!
```

Note: The defined-or operator `//` was added in Perl v5.10. It's more robust than using a logical or (`||`) as it won't default on the logically false values `''` and `0`.

Answer (score 4):

I like this way the most: Since Perl 5.10 you can use `//` to check if a variable is defined or not and provide an alternative value in case it is not.
So, an easy example is:

my $DEFAULT_VALUE = 42;

```
sub f {
    my ($p1, $p2) = @_;
    $p1 //= 'DEFAULT';
    $p2 // = $DEFAULT_VALUE;
}
```

Another option is using the `shift` instruction to get the params from `@_`:

```
sub f {
    my $p1 = shift // 'DEFAULT';
}
```

Source: https://perlmaven.com/how-to-set-default-values-in-perl

Answer (score 2):

There's the [Attribute::Default](http://search.cpan.org/~stephen/Attribute-Default-1.31/Default.pm) module on CPAN. Probably cleaner than this, and avoids a couple of complexities (such as, what if you want to pass `false` to your subroutine?).

I've also seen people use `my $var = exists @_[0] ? shift : "Default_Value";`, but Perl's documentation notes that [calling `exists` on arrays is deprecated](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html), so I wouldn't really recommend it.

Snippet of `Attribute::Default` from the doc page:

```
  sub vitals : Default({age => 14, sex => 'male'}) {
     my %vitals = @_;
     print "I'm $vitals{'sex'}, $vitals{'age'} years old, and am from $vitals{'location'}\n";
  }

   # Prints "I'm male, 14 years old, and am from Schenectady"
   vitals(location => 'Schenectady');
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to address your problem have been discussed in the other answers.
One thing that strikes me though is that you state that:

> ```
> sub hello {
>    print @_ || "Hello world";
> }
> ```
>
> And that works fine for if all you needed was one argument.

Have you actually tried that code? It will print the number of arguments or, when none provided, `Hello World`!
The reason for this is that the ||-operator takes precedence and forces the left-hand side in scalar context, thus reducing `@_` to the number of arguments you provide, NOT the arguments itself!
have a look at [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for more information on operators in Perl.
HTH,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

For more sugar, see also [Method::Signatures](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Method::Signatures):

```
func add($this = 23, $that = 42) {
    return $this + $that;
}
```