# Default true for optional argument in perl

Tags: perl

I am defining a method with an optional argument. Typically I would use something like this:

```
sub foo {
    ($self, $optarg) = @_;
    $optarg ||= 1;
}
```

I would like the optional argument to be treated as boolean, with the default being `true`. This obviously won't work with the above, since `$optarg` will evaluate to false if the argument is not passed in.

Is there a way to differentiate the absence of an argument being passed and a value that evaluates to false?

Comment: See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124138/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-to-a-perl-function) for an approach using prototypes (which should usually be avoided). Also [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543569/default-argument-values-in-subroutines). Possibly useful [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=161091).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This scales well to multiple optional arguments:

```
my $self = shift;
my $optarg = @_ ? shift : 1;
```

So does this, but it handles multiple required arguments better. Unfortunately, it violates the least-redundancy-possible principle.

```
my ($self, $optarg) = @_;
$optarg = 1 if @_ < 2;
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have Perl version 5.10 or later then you can replace `$optarg ||= 1` with `$optarg //= 1`, which will modify `$optarg` only if it is `undef`.

Alternatively, if you want to allow `undef` to be passed as an explicit false value, you can say `$optarg = 1 if @_ < 2`.

Answer (score 4):

```
my ( $self, $optarg ) = ( @_, 1 );
```

If it's "not passed in" then it won't be in the list and you'll get the `1`. Otherwise, assuming that the user knows how the method works, they shouldn't pass in anything that can be taken as false as a second argument, unless they mean it to be taken as a false value. (Of course, I'm not saying that knowledgeable users would never pass in a false value for a boolean.)

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying about not passing in a false as the second argument.

Comment: I don't understand what he is saying there either, but the code appears to work.

Comment: He's saying that if the user passes in two arguments (so `@_` has two elements), then the `1` won't get assigned. If `@_` has one element, then `1` gets assigned to `$optarg`. And if `@_` has no elements, the caller gets what he deserves.

Comment: @mob: That's what his code says. I disagree that that's what his prose says. If jordanm's code is well written, then it will handle any possible cases properly.

Answer (score 2):

You have gotten some good responses, so I'm just going to add one more possible option. [Method::Signatures](https://metacpan.org/module/Method%3a%3aSignatures) gives a nice syntax for methods with signatures including default values, handled in the way you expect.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package MyClass;

use Moo;
use Method::Signatures;

method foo ( $optarg = 1 ) {
  print "$optarg\n";
}

package main;

my $obj = MyClass->new;
$obj->foo;
$obj->foo(0);
```

Note that I use [Moo](https://metacpan.org/module/Moo) but its not needed for M::S. Note also that Moo enables `strict` and that this script is `strict` safe, even though it may not look it.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $optarg;
$optarg = 1 if not defined $optarg;
```

But do note @jordanm's comment, below

Comment: This works in all cases except for `foo(undef)`, which the user could expect to evaluate to false.

Comment: [`my $x = ... if ...` is an unreliable construct](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14197909/168657). Say `my $optarg; $optarg=1 if ...` instead.